# Combinatorics for functions in R, applying every p length combination of n functions

Tags: r, combinatorics

So I have n many functions that all operate over the same vector, lets say named x. For example, they could be:

```
s1 = function(x) mean(x)
s2 = function(x) sd(x)
...
sn = function(x) 1/length(x)*sum(x^3)
x <- c(3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 2, 1)
```

I want to generate all possible combinations of p many of these functions and apply each combination over the vector x.

What I've got so far is the combn function, but it seems to only work over a vector of characters like this:

```
a <- c("s1", "s2", "s3", ..., "sn")
b <- combn(a, 2)
b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] ...
[1,] "s1" "s1" "s2" ...
[2,] "s2" "s3" "s3" ...
```

What I'd need is a way to easily make a vector of the names of all of my functions, and a way to take a column of b above and apply all of the functions together.
I know of the each function in plyr, and it'd work perfectly except the output of combn is a vector of characters and each needs the actual functions as an argument, not the names. So the second thing I need is a way to convert

```
each("s1", "s2")
```

into

```
each(s1, s2)
```

where the top one is a column of the b matrix, and the second one uses the functions I defined at the start.

Ideally the eventual code would be applied to every column of b using an apply function.

Any help on the parts of this I can't figure out or an idea on another approach is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing the functions in a list:

```
funs <- list(
  mean
  , max
  , function(x) 1)
```

Then, let the data vector be:

```
set.seed(202)
z <- runif(100)
```

In order to get the results that you would like, you can apply them like this:

```
combn(
  length(funs)
  , 2
  , FUN = function(x) {
    lapply(
      # select the functions from the list that correspond to the combination
      funs[x]
      # apply each function in the list "fx" to the data vector
      , function(fx) fx(z)
    )
  }
)
```

The result looks like this:

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] 0.4971414 0.4971414 0.9969858
[2,] 0.9969858 1         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the string-> function lookup, just make a matrix of functions. Then `apply(b, 1:2)` to evaluate each function in turn:

```
> x <- c(3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 2, 1)
> a <- c(sum, mean, sd)
> b <- combn(a,2)
> str(b)
List of 6
 $ :function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  
 $ :function (x, ...)  
 $ :function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  
 $ :function (x, na.rm = FALSE)  
 $ :function (x, ...)  
 $ :function (x, na.rm = FALSE)  
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 3        
> apply(b, 1:2, function(f) f[[1]](x))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   27   27    3
[2,]    3    2    2
```

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question (as opposed to suggesting alternative workflows), we can access variables (such as functions) by name via the environment that encapsulates the session. Environments can be used similarly to other structures in R, such as lists and data frames.

The function `environment` can be used to get the current environment. The global environment is also available as `.GlobalEnv` (use `?environment` for more information). Here is an example of accessing functions via their names as strings:

```
> f <- function(x) 2 * x
> g <- function(x) x^2
> h <- function(x) 1 / x
> for (fun in c("f", "g", "h")) 
+ print(sprintf("%s(3) = %s", fun, environment()[[fun]](3)))
[1] "f(3) = 6"
[1] "g(3) = 9"
[1] "h(3) = 0.333333333333333"
```

For more on environments in R, take a look at [Wickham's *Advanced R* tutorial on environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).